# Determine whether this integral converges for 0 < p < 1?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

$$
 \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{x^p}
$$

I'm lost on how to approach this problem.

So far I've integrated it:

$$
 \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{x^p} = \lim_{b\to0}\frac{x^{1-p}}{1-p} \int_{a}^{b}
$$

But I don't know where to proceed from here to find the convergence.  How can I tell whether the limit exists and is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for $p<1$

$$
 \int_{0}^{a} \frac{dx}{x^p} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\epsilon}^{a} \frac{dx}{x^p} =\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{x^{1-p}}{1-p} \Bigg|_\epsilon^a=\frac{a^{1-p}}{1-p}
$$
hence the limit exists and then the integral is convergent.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit why you're able to go from the limit to that answer? Did you just plug in the limits, and since A is a constant, P from 0 to 1 forms a valid number?

Comment: Since $p<1$ then $1-p>0$ and then 
$$\epsilon^{1-p}\xrightarrow{\epsilon\to0}0$$

Comment: You're welcome.